# How to check in a sproc if a datetime2 value is the minimum value?

Tags: sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I have a SQL Server 2008 stored procedure that takes a datetime2 parameter. If the user passes in the minimum value I don't want to run part of the sproc. My question is, what is the best way to check if the value passed in is the c# DateTime.MinValue ?

Comment: "I don't want to run part of the sproc" - would that be "I don't want to run certain complete statements" or "I don't want *part* of some statements to apply"?

Comment: The sproc has two clean-up features. The datetime values define how much data to keep. The user defines this as number of days (so an integer value). If it is zero then that particular routine is not run. Originally I passed in this int value and let the sproc get the current datetime and shift it by the days to keep value. Problem with this is how to test this. By passing in the cut-off datetime I can run automated tests. This is why I need to pass in a min value instead of a zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insert the sample `DateTime.MinValue` value in Database in DateTime2 type. The result will be  0001-01-01 00:00:00.0000000

### Validation Part

```
if @Param != '0001-01-01 00:00:00.0000000'
begin
  -- Your code
end
```

Answer (score 0):

To control the flow in a stored procedure you should use [IF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182717.aspx). Min value for a [datetime2](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx) is `'0001-01-01'` which is the same for [C# datetime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.minvalue.aspx) so...

```sql
if @DatetimeParam > '0001-01-01'
begin
  -- Param is not min value, do stuff here.
end
```